# duplicate folder & contents, rename folder, pre-pend folder name to contents

Tags: applescript

Im hoping someone could help in building a small applescript.
So far i havent found a solution that does exactly what i need.

I have single folder with multiple files inside it. 
What i wish to do is to Duplicate that folder(with its contents) and have a prompt come up to input a new name for that folder. I also wish to Pre-pend the new name of that folder to all of the files inside it. Saving the folder(and contents) to a set location. (/Users/David/Custom)

**Eg. Original structure;**
    Folder name: "MainTemplate"
    Folder contents: "about.txt", "photo.jpg", "info.doc", etc.

**Post-duplication;**
    Folder name: "John The Dog"
    Folder contents: "John The Dog-about.txt", "John The Dog-photo.jpg", "John The Dog-info.doc", etc.

### Thank you for your time.

NEW

Ok, i've been working at this for 5+ hours. Re-naming the files is what i cant manage to figure out.
Could someone please help me with this part? Also, maybe the script could be improved?
Thanks!

```
on run {input, parameters}

tell application "Finder"

    set theFolder to folder "OS X:Users:David:Desktop:SCRIPT:script-copy"
    set targetFolder to folder "OS X:Users:David:Desktop:SCRIPT:script-copy-finished"


    display dialog "Which structure do you wish to duplicate?" buttons {"Structure-MAIN", "Structure-OTHER"}
    set chosenStructure to button returned of result


    if contents of chosenStructure is equal to "Structure-MAIN" then
        set chosenStructure to "OS X:Users:David:Desktop:SCRIPT:script-copy:-MAIN"
    else
        set chosenStructure to "OS X:Users:David:Desktop:SCRIPT:script-copy:-OTHER"
    end if


    display dialog "Specify a new folder name:" default answer "John The Dog"
    set newName to (text returned of result)
    set createNewStructure to make new folder at targetFolder with properties {name:newName}


    duplicate every file of entire contents of folder chosenStructure to createNewStructure





    set the_folder to name of folder chosenStructure
    repeat with this_file in (get files of entire contents of folder chosenStructure)

        set the_start to offset of "_" in ((name of this_file) as string)
        set the_stop to count (name of this_file as string)
        set name of this_file to (the_folder & (items the_start thru the_stop of (name of this_file as string)))
    end repeat

end tell


return input
end run
```

Comment: You need to provide some kind of script. This is a forum to teach people and help them in a sticky spot. Asking for hand out will not get you very far here.

Comment: Yes, search for applescript examples (there are tons) to: select the folder, copy the folder, rename the folder, iterate through files in a folder, rename items as iterated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append filenames with folder name \[dont understand\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513638/append-filenames-with-folder-name-dont-understand)

Answer (score 0):

you want to minimize tell blocks. The bigger they are the longer you get locked out from using that program. I cleaned it up a little and based on what you wrote the following should do the trick.

```
on run {input, parameters}

set chosenStructure to button returned of (display dialog "Which structure do you wish to duplicate?" buttons {"Structure-MAIN", "Structure-OTHER"})

if chosenStructure is equal to "Structure-MAIN" then
    set chosenStructure to "OS X:Users:David:Desktop:SCRIPT:script-copy:-MAIN"
else
    set chosenStructure to "OS X:Users:David:Desktop:SCRIPT:script-copy:-OTHER"
end if

set newName to text returned of (display dialog "Specify a new folder name:" default answer "John The Dog")

tell application "Finder"
    set theFolder to folder "OS X:Users:David:Desktop:SCRIPT:script-copy"
    set targetFolder to folder "OS X:Users:David:Desktop:SCRIPT:script-copy-finished"
    set createNewStructure to make new folder at targetFolder with properties {name:newName}

    duplicate every file of entire contents of folder chosenStructure to createNewStructure

    set the_folder to name of folder chosenStructure
    set folder_Contents to (get files of entire contents of folder chosenStructure)
end tell

repeat with this_file in folder_Contents

    tell application "Finder"
        set the_FileName to name of this_file
        set name of this_file to (the_folder & "-" & the_FileName)
    end tell
end repeat
```

end run