# Append filenames with folder name [dont understand]

Tags: applescript

Im struggling to understand how to rename(append) filenames inside a folder with the folders name.
**Eg,  about.txt, picture.jpg, etc  to become  folderName-about.txt, folderName-picture, etc.**
Im a complete noob at applescript, this is my first script ever!

```
on run {input, parameters}

tell application "Finder"
set theFolder to folder "OS X:Users:David:Desktop:SCRIPT:script-copy"
set targetFolder to folder "OS X:Users:David:Desktop:SCRIPT:script-copy-finished"

display dialog "Which structure do you wish to duplicate?" buttons {"Structure-MAIN", "Structure-OTHER"}
set chosenStructure to button returned of result

if contents of chosenStructure is equal to "Structure-MAIN" then
    set chosenStructure to "OS X:Users:David:Desktop:SCRIPT:script-copy:-MAIN"
else
    set chosenStructure to "OS X:Users:David:Desktop:SCRIPT:script-copy:-OTHER"
end if

display dialog "Specify a new folder name:" default answer "John The Dog"
set newName to (text returned of result)
set createNewStructure to make new folder at targetFolder with properties {name:newName}
duplicate every file of entire contents of folder chosenStructure to createNewStructure






set the_folder to name of folder chosenStructure
repeat with this_file in (get files of entire contents of folder chosenStructure)

    set the_start to offset of "_" in ((name of this_file) as string)
    set the_stop to count (name of this_file as string)
    set name of this_file to (the_folder & (items the_start thru the_stop of (name of this_file as string)))
end repeat

end tell


return input
end run
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: I dont know what to say? does the title not suggest it?

Comment: What specifically isn't working about the code you wrote?

Comment: The re-naming filenames. The last part of the script.
I want all filenames inside the folder to have the folders name prepended at the beginning of the filename. 
Eg, about.txt to become folderName-about.txt, etc.

Comment: What error or result are you getting from your file that is not what you're wanting?

Comment: I get an error of: Can’t make items 0 thru 14 of "Untitled 2.txt" into type Unicode text.
I am getting confused at the whole part of HOW to rename files.

Comment: Glade to see that 2hrs after making one post you duplicate it again... Not very good edicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want all filenames inside the folder to have the folders name
>   prepended at the beginning of the filename. Eg, about.txt to become
>   folderName-about.txt, etc.

Try this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    ...
    set the_folder to name of createNewStructure
    repeat with this_file in (get files of entire contents of createNewStructure)
        set name of this_file to the_folder & "-" & (name of this_file)
    end repeat
end tell
```

The whole Script:

```
set theFolder to ((path to desktop) as text) & "SCRIPT:script-copy"
set targetFolder to ((path to desktop) as text) & "SCRIPT:script-copy-finished"

display dialog "Which structure do you wish to duplicate?" buttons {"-MAIN", "-OTHER"}
set chosenStructure to ((path to desktop) as text) & "SCRIPT:script-copy:" & button returned of result

display dialog "Specify a new folder name:" default answer "John The Dog"
set newName to (text returned of result)

tell application "Finder"
    set createNewStructure to make new folder at targetFolder with properties {name:newName}
    duplicate every file of entire contents of folder chosenStructure to createNewStructure

    set the_folder to name of createNewStructure
    repeat with this_file in (get files of entire contents of createNewStructure)
        set name of this_file to the_folder & "-" & (name of this_file)
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: It is renaming the file but instead of prepending "John The Dog" its prepending the structure choice "-MAIN" or "-OTHER".

Comment: Yes, I took that from your script and was not sure about your intention. I've updated the answer.

Comment: That does work. Thank you. The only thing im puzzled about is the paths. How would i go about specifying a HD/partition? rather than Desktop.

Comment: You can set the paths like you did in your script. If you want to know the HFS path of a folder, run `choose folder` in ApplescriptEditor and look at the result.

Comment: If i set it to how i did originally:
set theFolder to folder "OS X:Users:David:Desktop:SCRIPT:script-copy"
I get an error: Expected end of line, etc. but found “"”.

Comment: Realized my mistake ("to folder" before path).