# On error re-open last dialog

Tags: applescript

I have a dialog which opens to input and store user input(name).
Upon error (which is is either due to no name entered or the name already exists) i want the dialog to re-open. Finally, if the second attempt fails again, open a dialog  which states that and exit.

The problem is, whether the name exists or does not, all 3 dialogs are ALWAYS displayed.
What am i missing?

```
try
    display dialog "Specify a new folder name:" default answer "John The Dog"
    set newName to (text returned of result)
on error errorMessage number errorNumber
end try

try
    display dialog "Specify a DIFFERENT folder name:" default answer "John The Dog12"
    set newName to (text returned of result)
on error errorMessage number errorNumber
end try

try
    display dialog "NAME ALREADY EXISTS! The program will now exit." with icon caution buttons {"EXIT"}
end try
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the code for checking if the name exists?

Comment: Hmm, thats all i have. The process would automatically show an error if i specified an existing name and would exit.
The full script is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513638/append-filenames-with-folder-name-dont-understand/24518268?noredirect=1#comment37963528_24518268

Comment: You are missing the code to create the new folder...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Note I did not test this but it should work. Just put this code in place of your code where you try to get the folder name.

You can basically create as many dialogTexts/defaultAnswers combinations as you want and it will work. Good luck.

```
-- get the names of all the folders in the targetFolder
tell application "Finder" to set targetFolderNames to name of folders of folder targetFolder

set dialogTexts to {"Specify a new folder name:", "Specify a DIFFERENT folder name:"}
set defaultAnswers to {"John The Dog", "John The Dog12"}

repeat with i from 1 to count of dialogTexts
    display dialog item i of dialogTexts default answer item i of defaultAnswers
    set newName to (text returned of result)
    if newName is not "" and newName is not in targetFolderNames then exit repeat

    if i is (count of dialogTexts) then
        display dialog "NAME ALREADY EXISTS! The program will now exit." with icon caution buttons {"EXIT"} default button 1
        return input
    end if
end repeat

-- do something with newName
```